# SQL select query on hashed password error

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple SQL query in MYSQL.

The data type of the password column is varchar(250)

Here is my query which is meant to select the row regarding the user using their hashed password in the database:

```
SELECT * FROM employeeDetails 
WHERE password = 'b''\xb4\xb7\xfbbA\x16\xa0\x97\xd5\x05\xd8\xb7\xfc\xeb\x06+
\x0f\x9b3)\xa3\x8d\xf6\x81\xc8\xccJ\xd6\x99\xbf\xf0\xc8'''
```

When I copy the password cell from the table here is the password I am trying to query in the query above:

```
'b'\xb4\xb7\xfbbA\x16\xa0\x97\xd5\x05\xd8\xb7\xfc\xeb\x06+
\x0f\x9b3)\xa3\x8d\xf6\x81\xc8\xccJ\xd6\x99\xbf\xf0\xc8'''
```

The problem is, It doesn't return any rows!

Comment: Try surrounding the password string with quotes `WHERE password = "'b''\xb4\xb7\xfbbA\x16\xa0\x97\xd5\x05\xd8\xb7\xfc\xeb\x06+
\x0f\x9b3)\xa3\x8d\xf6\x81\xc8\xccJ\xd6\x99\xbf\xf0\xc8'''"`

Comment: @Rob Moll: Hrm, if that were the problem, the query would crash, I don't think it would respond with "0 rows."

Answer (score 0):

In your request you must precede the quotes and the antislashes characters by an escape character (\)

select row with the request :

```
SELECT * FROM employeeDetails WHERE PASSWORD =
"\'b\'\\\xb4\\\xb7\\\xfbbA\\\x16\\\xa0\\\x97\\\xd5\\\x05\\\xd8\\\xb7\\\xfc\\\xeb\\\x06
+
\\\x0f\\\x9b3)\\\xa3\\\x8d\\\xf6\\\x81\\\xc8\\\xccJ\\\xd6\\\x99\\\xbf\\\xf0\\\xc8\'\'\'"
```

Comment: Hi, youchech!  Welcome to StackOverflow!  To my understanding, apostrophes only need to be escaped within apostrophe-defined strings, i.e., `'array\'s'`, and not when within quote-defined strings, i.e., `"array's"`.

Answer (score 0):

Is your hash string correct?  It looks as though it may have been mangled by a converter of some type.  Look: `\xfbbA`, capital A?  That shouldn't be there.  This `b''\xb4`, the b'' seems quite out of place, etc..

Look at this command:

```
SELECT UNHEX('4d7953514c');
```

The result is:

```
+---------------------+
| UNHEX('4d7953514c') |
+---------------------+
| MySQL               |
+---------------------+
```

"MySQL" is just an arbitrary string I chose, it could have been any text value.  But it certainly will error out on some of your chars.

```
mysql> SELECT UNHEX("'b''");
+-----------------------+
| SELECT UNHEX("'b''"); |
+-----------------------+
| NULL                  |
+-----------------------+
```

If you wanted to actually compare the values, you'll notice your DB-field probably looks like: `Ll▒▒$o4|l▒▒Ődn▒▒`, when doing a straight `SELECT passwordfield FROM YourTable`.

But you can get a decipherable value with....

```
mysql> SELECT HEX(passwordfield) FROM YourTable;
```

And this returns something like...

```
mysql> select HEX(Password) from User;
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| HEX(Password)                                                    |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 294C6CADBE246F3
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Now that you can look at the raw, hexadecimal *in the database* and *in the hashed password*, you should be able to definitely tell if they match, and if not, what's different between the two and track it down.

You may need to fix the hashing, fix password cleansing, fix MySQL field-escaping, or use `HEX()` or `UNHEX()` in your insert/select queries, it's really hard to tell without knowing any more.  The above should hopefully provide sufficient knowledge to debug further.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why looking for a hashed password.  I would think you query the WHO is attempting login, then once that record is returned (if one so exists), THEN you have the hashed column returned and you can compare locally.  What happens if for whatever strange reason you get a duplicate coincidental hash (depending on how you build your underlying stored hash). Do you let person "A" login as person "X"?  Now you wont have to worry about the query of the hashed password value.  If you never get the person, who cares, the hash is irrelevant.